# Fetch events from EKEventStore and show in tableView in Swift iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, ios8, ekeventstore

I'm trying to create a small application that will fetch all events and will show them in a tableView.

My specific questions are:

1. Is my `fetchEvents()` method is implemented correctly?
2. Where should I call the `fetchEvent()` method in order to show the list when the app opens (is it in `viewDidLoad`?) and to refresh it after the addition/edit of a new event?

Thanks!

This is my code for the `MasterViewController.swift` file:

```
import UIKit
import EventKitUI

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController , EKEventEditViewDelegate{

var objects = NSMutableArray()
let eventStore =  EKEventStore()


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

    //self.fetchEvents()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {

    let controller = EKEventEditViewController()

    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType(), completion: {granted, error in })
    controller.eventStore = eventStore

    controller.editViewDelegate = self
    self.presentModalViewController(controller, animated: true)


    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}

func eventEditViewController(controller: EKEventEditViewController!, didCompleteWithAction action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

func fetchEvents() -> NSMutableArray {

    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType(), completion: {granted, error in })

    let endDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800*10);   //This is 10 weeks in seconds
    let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(NSDate(), endDate: NSDate(), calendars: nil)

    var events = NSMutableArray(array: self.eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate))

    return events

    /*
    var indexes = NSMutableIndexSet(index: 5)

    indexes.addIndex(4)

    objects.insertObjects(events, atIndexes: indexes) */

    // Create the start date components



   /* NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1;

    let oneDayAgo = currentCalendar.date dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents*/

}

// #pragma mark - Segues

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate
        (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).detailItem = object
    }
}

// #pragma mark - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate
    cell.textLabel.text = object.description
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        objects.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, You should be doing the rest of the work in your `fetchEvents` function inside the callback for `eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType`:

```
func fetchEvents() -> NSMutableArray {
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType()) completion: {
        granted, error in
        ... the rest of the code ...
    })
}
```

of course now that it's async, you'll need to return the data in a callback instead of returning it:

```
func fetchEvents(completed: (NSMutableArray) -> ()) {
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType()) completion: {
        granted, error in
        let endDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800*10);   //This is 10 weeks in seconds
        let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(NSDate(), endDate: NSDate(), calendars: nil)
        let events = NSMutableArray(array: self.eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate))
        completed(events)
    })
}
```

But now you have another problem... you're using self in the closure, thereby capturing a reference, which can lead to a "[reference cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_66)". In this particular case, I'm pretty sure that won't happen because `requestAccessToEntityType()` won't keep a reference to your closure (I'm *pretty* sure), but it's a good idea to use `[weak self]` whenever you you use `self` inside a callback function:

once you've done that, self is an optional though, so you need to make sure it's not nil…

```
func fetchEvents(completed: (NSMutableArray) -> ()) {
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType()) completion: { [weak self]
        granted, error in
        if let strongSelf = self {
            let endDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800*10);   //This is 10 weeks in seconds
            let predicate = strongSelf.eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(NSDate(), endDate: NSDate(), calendars: nil)
            let events = NSMutableArray(array: strongSelf.eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate))
            completed(events)
        }
    })
}
```

but looking a little closer, we never use `self` just `self.eventStore`, so we can capture a weak reference to that directly instead:

```
func fetchEvents(completed: (NSMutableArray) -> ()) {
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType()) completion: { [weak weakEventStore = self.eventStore]
        granted, error in
        if let eventStore = weakEventStore {
            let endDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800*10);   //This is 10 weeks in seconds
            let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(NSDate(), endDate: NSDate(), calendars: nil)
            let events = NSMutableArray(array: eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate))
            completed(events)
        }
    })
}
```

finally, you really ought to check for errors instead of ignoring them, (`granted` could be false, meaning the user didn't give you access, or there could have been an error (so you need to check if `error` is nil (`if error { /* handle failure */ }`)

PS - I have [working code which uses event kit on github](https://github.com/jiaaro/swift-grocery) which you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborated answer! One small thing, how and from where do I call the fetchEvents() method? Is it in viewDidLoad? And I tried the call self.fetchEvents(objects), but, I get this error: Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type '(NSMutableArray) -> Void'.    Thanks!

Comment: @shila viewDidLoad is a fine place to call it, the issue is that you need to pass a callback: `self.fetchEvents(completed: { (events: NSMutableArray) -> Void in })`